# Pardot,google adwords,salesforce and google analytics setup query for tracking GCLID and GA visitor ID from google advertisement?

Tags: community, pardot, google, google-analytics, adwords

I am new to google analytics..and want to track google click id and analytics visitor id from google ads so how can I do this using auto-tagging..? and do we require UTM parameters along with auto-tagging while tracking cookie values. And if also when I was using google analytics tracking id code snippet do we need to additionally use google tag manager code snippets in the web form...Because I am getting confused, I am unable to get a visitor cookie(GCLID and GA visitor ID). Pls, help me out in this setup.
this is my web to lead form code...what is the mistake in it.

```
<html>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-1', 'auto');
ga(function(tracker) {
  var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
  tracker.set('dimension1',clientId);
});
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>

</head>

<body>

<form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
<script> 
        window.onload = function getGclid() {        
             document.getElementById("GCLID").value = (name = new    
        RegExp('(?:^|;\\s*)gclid=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) ? 
        name.split(",")[1] : "";
            document.getElementById("GA visitor Id").value = (name = new    
        RegExp('(?:^|;\\s*)_ga=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) ? 
         name.split(",")[1].split(".").slice(2).join(".") : "";
        }
        </script>
<input type=hidden name="oid" value="oid value">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://google.com">
<input id="GCLID" name="GCLID"   type="hidden" /><br>
<input id="GA visitor Id" name="GA visitor Id"   type="hidden" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setCookie(name, value, days){
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000)); 
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires;
}
function getParam(p){
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + p + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
var gclid = getParam('gclid');
if(gclid){
    var gclsrc = getParam('gclsrc');
    if(!gclsrc || gclsrc.indexOf('aw') !== -1){
        setCookie('gclid', gclid, 90);
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```